# Finding numbers whose product is a particular number?

Tags: products

Is there a standard way to formulate and evaluate the following? Basically, I want to find 100 possibly distinct (some numbers can be repeated) real numbers ($0 < 1 + \frac{n_i}{100} < 5$) such that:

$\sqrt[100]{\prod_{i=1}^{100} \left ( 1+\frac{n_i}{100} \right )} = 1.07$

It is ok if there are multiple solutions.

**EDIT**: Apologies! I made a mistake in writing the constraint.

I believe this can be simplified as:

$\prod_{i=1}^{100} m_i = 1.07^{100}$

where $m_i = 1 + \frac{n_i}{100}$ and $0 < m_i < 5$

After this I'm stuck - Are there any numerical methods to solve this?

Comment: I don't think such a set of numbers exists. The geometric mean of 100 numbers (which appears on the left) is bounded by the maximum, which in turn is $\le 1.05$.

Comment: For sure it is not an optimization problem. You are not maximizing nor minimizing.

Comment: @SergioParreiras: Thank you. I edited the title to reflect this.

Comment: @HansEngler: Great point! Sorry but I made a mistake in writing the constraint. I updated my question.

Comment: So take $n_i = 7$?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: please consider submitting your comment as an answer

Comment: @SergioParreiras, I'm still not sure if that's what OP wanted to ask. If "possibly distinct" actually means "not all equal", then this would be a more interesting question.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė: Thank you for your answer. I just started exploring something very similar to your solution. I'll get back in a bit. And yes, by `possibly distinct` I meant `not all equal` - I just want't sure if there was a solution and hence the ambiguity in my sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

1. Start with  Karolis Juodelė's suggestion: all $n_i=7$.
2. Keep all $n_i=7$ for $i>2$.
3. Change $n_1$ a little bit and (similar to the implicit function theorem) solve the original equation for $n_2$ as a function of $n_1$.
4. Since you are moving $n_1$ just a bit, $n_2$ will move just a bit as well, so all inequality constraints will hold.
5. After you got new values of $n_1$ and $n_2$ then you can leave their values fixed, and move on to the next numbers, $n_3$ and $n_4$ and so on...

Comment: I assume $n$ means integer. In that case, are there any solutions besides $n_i = 7$?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė  The question reads,  "100 possibly distinct (some numbers can be repeated) **real** numbers". In my answer $n_i$ is a real number, not necessarily an integer.